# Is it possible to put some condition where the specific URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im doing the active in sidebar. After the admin logged in(ofcourse it will automatically redirect to localhost:/xxx/Admin/index or localhost:/xxx/Admin/) and the active is in the dashboard. 
When the admin clicked the user management(it will redirect to localhost:/xxx/Admin/UserAccount) then the active will be change into the user management/.. The question is, is it possible to make an if statement, when the specific URL is that/this?

**View**

```
<li class="<?= highlight_menu('Administrator/userAccount',TRUE)?>treeview">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>User Management</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a href="<?= base_url(). 'Administrator/userAccount'?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> View users account</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

**Common Helper**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function highlight_menu($menu_item, $has_routes = FALSE)
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    if(! $has_routes) // activate only if the exact URL is found
        return (uri_string()==$menu_item) ? 'active-menu':'';
    $controller =   strtolower($CI->router->fetch_class());// get controller name
    $method     =   strtolower($CI->router->fetch_method()); // get method name
    return (strtolower($menu_item) == $controller."/".$method) ? 'active-menu' : ''; // activate only if the controller and method matches
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the session or not?

Comment: you can either use a cookie or db column to store data;
 `ischeckedUserManagement` or `userStatus` in User Table. According to one of them, you can easily determine where do you want to redirect

Comment: It's better to use role based login and use seesion role for such kind of problems.

Comment: I know the loggin session, the problem is how should I put active sidebar when the specific is URL is this Admin/userAccount?

Answer (score 1):

The following lines of code will help you to highlight a menu item depending on the current URL. For simplicity and re-usability I am adding this as a helper function into my helper file. (I already have a helper file added at  application/helpers/common_helper.php and auto-loading it when the application starts)

Read more about helper functions here

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html

```
function highlight_menu($menu_item, $has_routes = FALSE)
{
    $CI         = get_instance();
    if(! $has_routes) // activate only if the exact URL is found
        return (uri_string()==$menu_item) ? 'active-menu':'';
    $controller =   strtolower($CI->router->fetch_class());// get controller name
    $method     =   strtolower($CI->router->fetch_method()); // get method name
    return (strtolower($menu_item) == $controller."/".$method) ? 'active-menu' : ''; // activate only if the controller and method matches
}
```

Then in your view, add the menu items something like

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu_item">
        <a class="menu-class <?php echo highlight_menu('controller/method_name', TRUE);?>" href="<?php echo base_url('controller/method_name');?>">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in you CSS, use `.active-menu` selector to add style for the active menu item.

Comment: Where can I find the common_helper?

Comment: @Angel You can create a common_helper.php (the name common is arbitrary) inside your application/helpers folder and add your commonly used functions there. Read more about helpers here 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/index.html?highlight=helper

Don't forget to load your helper file before calling these functions

Comment: I followed the instructions that you've said to me

Comment: What is the output? add a space before treeview 
<li class="<?= highlight_menu('Administrator/userAccount',TRUE)?> treeview">

Comment: Put your styles for active menu item in css as
.active-menu
{
/** Your styles here **/ 
}

Comment: Nothing happens sir,

Comment: @Angel I think your controller name is administrator and method name is userAccount. Could you please inspect the element using developer tools (in chrome or firebug) and check whether the class 'active-menu' has added your menu link, when you browse that page?